# Почему transition не работает?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы span "Label" плавно подымался на верх?
У меня просто что-то не работает свойство transition в CSS...

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.div0 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    transition: all .4s;
}

input[type=text]+span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .6s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: royalblue;
}

input[type=text]:focus+span {
    transition: all .4s;
    color: royalblue;
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div0">
        <input type="text" class="sawd" onfocusout="this.value=''">
        <span id="lox">Label</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы двигалось надо чтобы было задано **НАЧАЛЬНОЕ** и **КОНЕЧНОЕ** состояния

вы двигаете текст вверх и задали конечное состояние `top: -16px;`, но вы не задали начальное состояние `top: 0;`

задайте и у вас все получится

```css
.div0 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    transition: all .4s;
}

input[type=text]+span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: royalblue;
}

input[type=text]:focus+span {
    transition: all 0.4s;
    color: royalblue;
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div0">
        <input type="text" class="sawd" onfocusout="this.value=''">
        <span id="lox">Label</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.div0 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    transition: all .4s;
}

input[type=text]+span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .6s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: royalblue;
}

input[type=text]:focus+span {
    animation: movement .6s ease-in-out;
    color: royalblue;
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
@keyframes movement {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: -16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div0">
        <input type="text" class="sawd" onfocusout="this.value=''">
        <span id="lox">Label</span>
    </div>
</body>
```